# Can't get props work with Vue component

Tags: vue.js

```
var userContent = Vue.extend({
props: ['myarr']
template:'<div v-for="m in myarr">{{m}}</div>'
})


var vm = new Vue(
{
el:'body', 
components: {userContent}
  data: 
   {
      myarr : ["one", "two"]
   }
})
```

Here is my jsfeedle code https://jsfiddle.net/ojrs6kk5/1/

I am trying to get data from value of `myarr` from `data` in main Vue App, but it does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. You are interpolating inside the `div` tag
2. There are no commas separating the properties in your program,
3. You are declaring a prop (`myarr`) and then not using it

You can see a working version of your code here

https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/ojrs6kk5/2/

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with that jsfiddle but it does not render any html.